# Ruby - Thor execute a specific Task first

Tags: ruby, initialization, task, thor

Is it possible to call a specific task first, when i run a thor task?

my Thorfile:

```
class Db < Thor

  desc "show_Version", "some description ..."
  def show_version # <= needs a database connection
    puts ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
  end

  private

  def connect_to_database # <= call this always when a task from this file is executed
    # connect here to database
  end

end
```

I could write the "connect_to_database" method in every task but that seems not very DRY.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `invoke` to run other tasks:

```
def show_version
  invoke :connect_to_database
  # ...
end
```

That will also make sure that they are run only once, otherwise you can just call the method as usual, e.g.

```
def show_version
  connect_to_database
  # ...
end
```

Or you could add the call to the constructor, to have it run first in every invocation:

```
def initialize(*args)
  super
  connecto_to_database
end
```

The call to `super` is very important, without it Thor will have no idea what to do.

Comment: i want to write the call to "connect_to_database" only once.
like you would write it in a regular class in the constructor

Comment: Try adding a constructor: `def initialize(*args); super; connecto_to_database; end`

Comment: I added that variant to my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

A rather under-documented feature of thor is the method `default_task`. Passed a symbol from within your thor script, you can set it to run a specific task and, using invoke, run other tasks.

For example:

```rb
default_task :connect_to_database
```